# Tiggr vs Application Craft

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile, cordova, cloud, builder

in the last months the development of mobile apps has become more and more a focus of mine. I already created a few apps with PhoneGap and also dived in into mobile frameworks like jQuery Mobile ans Sencha Touch.

In a next step I would like to use a mobile apps builder and I stumbled on [Tiggr](http://gotiggr.com) and [Application Craft](http://www.applicationcraft.com/). There are probably even more.

So I wanted to ask if some people here already have experience with those two or maybe even another app builder and share it with us. As both seem to cover the same area and I am not so interested in learning them all. I would like to know if someone can tell me which is "better".

I know that there has been a big topic about PhoneGap vs Titanium Appcelerator that helped me a lot so I hope I can get some helpful answers about this topic as well.

Thanks for reading,
Marvin

Answer (score 2):

I have been using Application Craft for about a month (on and off) and so far i'm really impressed.  They seem to be putting LOTS of work into it: things have broken only a couple of times, never anything serious.  Also, they are building really thorough documentation, etc. they host the apps for free, and they seem to be adding features etc all the time.  I would bet that in a year or so they will be huge; quality services on the net tend to grow fast thankfully.

I hadn't heard about Tiggr until now.  From what i can see on their site, it looks as though their free service is far inferior to what Application Craft offer.  They may be worth a try too?

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I haven't specifically tried Tiggr or ApplicationCraft, but as you've already mentioned there are quite a few different app creation systems out there, all of which work in slightly different ways. Many, for example MobileRoadie or AppBaker, supply a series of pre-built templates that you can customise and plug together in various ways. This is great if their templates support the type of app you want, but there's often no scripting support so if you want something custom you need to pay for their developers to add the features you need, or you should go elsewhere.

If you want complete control over how your app looks and works then you should use a more IDE-like system with built-in scripting support. Things to look out for in such a system would be a good code editor, a way of immediately previewing your app inside the tools, decent documentation, support, and examples. If you're planning a cross-platform app, you'll want a system that can simulate your app running on different phone screen sizes, so you can tune your GUI appropriately.

[AppFurnace](http://www.appfurnace.com) is a new cloud-based app development platform that provides all of the above (I should point out that I work for AppFurnace, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Tiggr Mobile is a great service!  Check out thier tutorials on creating an app that will run on any mobile device at http://blog.gotiggr.com/.  They've also received good press and have an impressive gallery of apps that users have created and submitted.

Comment: I checked and it support iphone and android but no support for wp7,wp8 or wp8.1 :-(

Answer (score 0):

You should probably put NS Basic/App Studio on your list as well. It provides a complete IDE, including a 'drag and drop' interface for adding elements to your forms. The overall feel is something like Visual Studio. You can program in JavaScript or Basic. More info at http://www.nsbasic.com/app.

(disclosure: I work for NS Basic)